# Can you create custom variables in paypals payment system?

Tags: php, variables, paypal

I have used item_name, item_price and item_number but there is no option to include 'description'. I want to pass over the description of each item in the basket over to paypal. Is there a way to create a custom variable to pass over to paypal?

Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting Paypal to do with this information? You can pass them anything you want, but if the system doesn't know what to do with it then it would be useless anyway...

Comment: Paypal considers `item_name` to be, not only the name, but the description of the item. Use it as such if you want the description to show up in the basket. See [HTML Variables for Individual Items](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HF080O3)

Answer (score 0):

i would store all information needed inside a session before payment is made

```
$_SESSION['item_name'] = $item_name;
$_SESSION['item_price'] = $item_price;
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Visit  http://www.developer.paypal.com

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside